# Avoiding to instantiate an object with invalid argument

Tags: php, class, oop, instantiation

I'm currently developing a little private project in order to get more acquainted with PHP and OOP in general. Basically, I am creating a little app that is able to create posts and tag them.

The classes are organised like this so far:

- **Post**
  Represents a post in the database, and has functions such as `editPost()`, `attachTag()`, etc.
- **Tag**
  Represents a tag in the database, and similarly, has functions such as `editTag()`, etc.
- **PostUtils**
  This is like a management interface, it is used to create/delete new posts and tags, list 
  them, etc.

Now, when I instantiate a new Post object, I do so by passing the post ID as its required argument. When I do that, I would like to be able to check first whether the ID is valid or not. So far I've been doing that by using a method in the PostUtils class (`isValidID($id)`), so that the controller can perform a check before the Post class is instantiated. However, I've been reading about the [Tell, Don't Ask](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask) principle, and it seems to me that I should perform this check within the Post class itself instead.

Ideally, I would like the object to be instantiated only when a valid ID is passed. So my question is, what would be the best behaviour for the class when a non-valid ID is passed instead? Does this make sense at all? Or does my whole architecture need to be changed to start with?

Thank you very much for your time, it is really appreciated :)

Comment: If you don't want an object to be created if required data is missing or invalid then you should create a static factory method on the `Post` class.  Similar to how [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) works.

Comment: If I understand that correctly, I need to look into factory method design patterns. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
public class Post
{
  private function __construct($id)
  {
    /* Private constructor... do your normal initialization here */
  }

  private static function isValidID($id)
  {
    if (/*... check if $id is valid ... */) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  public static function create($id)
  {
    if (!self::isValidID($id)) {
      return NULL; // Or throw an exception
    }

    return new Post($id);
  }
}
?>
```

And then you would use it, like:

```
<?php
  $post = Post::create(1234);

  if (is_null($post)) {
    /* Invalid ID */
  }
?>
```

Or if you opted to throw an exception:

```
<?php
  try {
    $post = Post::create(1234);
  } catch (YourInvalidIDException $e) {
    /* Invalid ID */
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense to me!

Comment: @SeanBright You're welcome. Tbh I'm not sure if I'm supposed to edit such things myself, after all that'd be the wiki aspect of SO

Comment: By the way, I've been thinking… If I choose to instantiate the object only through a static method, is there any way I can prevent the object to be instantiated otherwise (e.g. `$post = new Post(43)`)? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. You make the constructor `private` as in my example above.

Comment: @SeanBright: Oh I see, I somehow missed that. Thanks for the clarification!